# Objective C Naming Convention for an object that owns itself

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode

With the latest releases of XCode that contain static analyzers, some of my objects are throwing getting analyzer issues reported.  Specifically, I have an object that owns itself and is responsible for releasing itself, but should also be returned to the caller and possibly retained there manually.

If I have a method like `+ (Foo) newFoo` the analyzer sees the word New and reports an issue in the caller saying that `newFoo` is expected to return an object with retain +1, and it isn't being released anywhere.  If I name it `+ (Foo) getFoo` the analyzer reports an issue in that method, saying there's a potential leak because it's not deallocated before returning.

My class basically looks like this:

```
+ (Foo *) newFoo {
    Foo *myFoo = [[[Foo new] retain] autorelease];
    [myFoo performSelectorInBackground:@selector(bar) withObject:nil];
    return myFoo;
}

- (void) bar {
    //Do something that might take awhile
    [self release];
}
```

The object owns itself and when its done, will release itself, but there's nowhere that it's being stored, so the static analyzer sees it as a leak somewhere.  Is there some naming or coding convention to help?

Comment: in newFoo does it really return foo and not myFoo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your implementation of `newFoo` you create and return a `Foo` instance with a logical retain count of +1. Cocoa [Memory Management Rules](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000043-SW1) require that methods prefixed with `new` must return a retained object. But they also state that object ownership is passed to the calling method. That means, you cannot release the object on the background thread.

Let me propose a clearer and more Cocoa-ish way:

Rename `newFoo` to something like `fooInBackground` (where foo should be a verb). This new method returns an autoreleased instance, letting the thread doing it's own ownership. `performSelectorInBackground:withObject:` retains both the receiver and the object argument, so there's no reason to retain it otherwise and manually release it in the background method.

```
+ (Foo *) fooInBackground {
    Foo *myFoo = [[[Foo alloc] init] autorelease];
    [myFoo performSelectorInBackground:@selector(bar) withObject:nil];
    return myFoo;
}
```

Sidenote: Since you return the `myFoo` object from `fooInBackground` it would be a bug to just release instead of autoreleasing the object before returning it. The background thread could be finished before the first thread had a chance to retain `myFoo` in the calling method. I'm just saying that because there seems to exist an (ill-founded) preoccupation against autorelease with all the new iPhone programmers coming to Cocoa.

Comment: The above code is one example, but there are others which are more difficult to deal with.  One, for example, sits around waiting for a UIButton to be clicked and releases itself after it's done handling the click.  Since the UIButton doesn't retain targets, it has to retain itself.  Any thoughts there?

Comment: Accepted for partial answer; still looking for a better solution